# starting another amazon-emr cluster when the first one finishes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have a main emr cluster doing a series of step jobs and I have to add 8 more steps.

The problem I'm facing is that the first EMR cluster is too powerful for those 8 steps.

Thus I was wondering if there is an easy way to automatically spin up another cluster one the first one finishes (it would be downgrading from r4.8xlarge to r4.xlarge, 8 to 10 instances).

Should I call a CloudFormation template.sh to be activate at the end of the first one for this purpose?

Those steps takes 4h no matter the hardware, which is why I'm aiming to reduce the cost of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this.

The one I would choose is with Amazon DataPipeline or Step functions. 
Your first emr cluster's job is EMR activity one. You can add another step in your pipeline as another EMR activity to add the subsequent steps with a smaller emr cluster.

Comment: Ooh super cool! We are using the data-pipeline for the first one already, I'll check how I can add a subsequent step :)

Comment: I've tried several things, but I can't have the second cluster starting once the first one finishes. I've tried to add the property "parent" on the previous EMR cluster, but I have the error "parent should be of type Undefined".
I don't understand how to pass the emractivity as a step :(
Do you know how to orchestrate it?